# Java Looping Quizzes

Tags: loops, average

So I'm quite in trouble in debugging this code and would like to ask for your help..

So this is the code:
import java.io.*;

public class PrefEx2{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

```
    int quiz, ave, sum=0;

    BufferedReader inpt = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // System.out.print("Section 1");

    for (int sect=1; sect<4; sect++){
        System.out.print("Section " + sect);
    for (int x=1; x<4; x++){
        System.out.println("\n Student " + x);
     for (int y=1; y<4; y++){
        System.out.print("Quiz " + y + ": ");
        quiz=Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());
        sum=sum+quiz;
     }
        ave=sum/3;
        System.out.print("Average: " + ave);
        System.out.println("");
     }

  }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

}

What I want to show on the output:

Section 1 (up to 3 section)

-Student 1

-- Quiz 1: xx

-- Quiz 2: xx

-- Quiz 3: xx

-- Average: xx

-Student 2

-- Quiz 1: xx

-- Quiz 2: xx

-- Quiz 3: xx

-- Average: xx

-Student 3

-- Quiz 1: xx

-- Quiz 2: xx

-- Quiz 3: xx

-- Average: xx

============================

So the problem in this code is that the average summing itself up
Like for e.g. 
Average of student 1 is 94
then on the next average it goes like 186 instead of 92..
I hope you can help me I need this for our proj.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a sum=0 before this line

```
for (int y=1; y<4; y++){
```

to reset the value for each student

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the variable sum. You have to reset that after avg calc

Answer (score 0):

You should assign sum=0; before
for (int y=1; y<4; y++)